# Como valido que el usuario no de espacios en blanco en el TextBox en C# MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

Buenas gente tengo un problema que no entiendo como validar que el usuario cuando haga un espacio en blanco en el textbox este sea negado.
Había visto algo que con el evento keypress pero en mvc no encuentro como hacerlo, y quisiera hacerlo parecido.
No se si pueda hacer la validación en controlador o en la vista como normalmente se hace o tal vez pueda ser controlado esa validación en el modelo, ya que aun no entiendo del todo este tipo de modelamiento.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Mantenedor de Isapres</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home")">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Isapres</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="content">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Crear Isapre</h3>

                        <div class="card-tools">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Isapres", new { })" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Volver <i class="fas fa-backward"></i></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {

                        <!-- /.card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Descripcion" class="offset-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    @Html.TextBox("Nombre", Model.Nombre, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("Nombre")

                                </div>
                            </div>

                           

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center">Guardar Isapre</button>
                        </div>

                    }

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: Hace mucho que no hago nada WEB con MVC en C# pero y no se qué name usa tu INPUT en el FORM pero, te dejo una respuesta que te puede guiar

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, puedes usar puramente `Javascript` con el evento [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar su comportamiento predeterminado, crearemos un script:

```js
var espacioEnblanco = document.querySelector('[name="nombreUsuario"]');

espacioEnblanco.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){
  var teclaEspacio = e.keyCode;
  if (teclaEspacio === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nombreUsuario">
```

Una breve explicación, es que primero declaramos una variable que se encargue de escuchar la acción de keypress dentro del input 'nombreUsuario' y luego una variable que recoja el valor de la tecla espacio (en decimal es el 32) [ASCII](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii/ascii-space.html) entonces si el usuario presiona esa tecla, con el evento ya mencionado nos encargamos de que no "funcione". Espero que te sirva